# What is wrong with this jquery function?

Tags: jquery, anchor, scrollto

I am using jquery to scroll to an anchor.... It works fine with a html button calling the function...

But when i call it from server side i get the id but it doesn't seem to work for me...

```
LinkButton lb1 = (LinkButton)sender;
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(lb1, typeof(LinkButton),
 "scroll","goToByScroll('myAnchor')", true);
```

And my function is,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function goToByScroll(id) {alert(id);
   $('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: $("#" + id).offset().top }, 'slow');
   }
 </script>
```

I got the error `$("#" + id).offset() is null`

I get the alert id of my anchor but why doesn't it work....

Here is my anchor...

`<a name="myAnchor" id="myAnchor"></a>`

Its working perfectly in a html button,

`<input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" onclick="goToByScroll('myAnchor');"/>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try bringing your function to get scrolltop out of that area--not sure animate() can handle it.

```
var topOff = $("#" + id).offset().top;
$('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: topOff}, 'slow');
```

And if that doesn't do it, I dunno, I seem to remember having to convince jQuery I meant to make things a string in the selector, so `$("#"+id+"")`.